# How to fill 'initial value' in Django forms with current user data?

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

I went ahead and created a Form to update the user database entry.

```
class UserUpdateForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ("username", "first_name", "last_name", "email")
```

But when I render the form all input fields are empty. How do I populate them with the user's data like current username and email?

I use Bootstrap 5 to style it, but that should matter:

```html
<div class="mb-3">
   <label for="{{ form.first_name.id_for_label }}" class="form-label">{{ form.first_name.label }}</label>
   {{ form.first_name|addcss:"form-control"}}
</div>
```

Problem is, I render the input field with the Django template engine and don't specifiy it myself. My idea was to chain template filters:

```
<div class="mb-3">
   <label for="{{ form.username.id_for_label }}" class="form-label">{{ form.username.label }}</label>
   {{ form.username|addcss:"form-control"|addplaceholder:user.username}}
</div>
```

But that didn't work because the first filter converts it to a widget:

```
@register.filter(name="addcss")
def addcss(field, css):
    return field.as_widget(attrs={"class": css})
```

Maybe you can recommend me a way on how to modify that filter or tell me a complety different approach.

Comment: `form = UserUpdateForm(initial={'first_name': 'users first name'})` will initialize the form with the first_name field filled in.  Check out https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/forms/api/#initial-form-values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
form = UserUpdateForm(instance=request.user)
```

you have to set init data.

Answer (score 0):

When you create the form within the view you can specify an instance:

```
form = UserUpdateForm(instance=user_instance)
```

Rendering this form in the template will show values from `user_instance` in the form.
You can also specify an `initial` dictionary for the form but the is usually only for empty forms useful.

Answer (score 0):

I decided to pass an email into args in 'RegisterUserView' and then in 'CodeConfirmationUserView' retrieve this value in 'get_initial' method which obtains an 'email' from self.kwargs and then passes it into my template as an initial data.

**views.py**

```
class RegisterUserView(ConfirmationCodeMixin, ErrorMessageMixin, SuccessMessageMixin, CreateView):
    model = get_user_model()
    form_class = RegisterUserForm
    template_name = 'users/register.html'
    extra_context = {'title': 'Registration'}
    success_message = "The confirmation code has been successfully sent!"

    def form_valid(self, form):
        try:
            user = form.save(commit=False)
        except UserNotInExternalResource as error:
            messages.error(request=self.request, message=error)
            return redirect(to=reverse_lazy(REGISTER_URL))
        # ...

        return redirect(to=reverse_lazy('users:code_confirmation', args=(user.email,)))


class CodeConfirmationUserView(ConfirmationCodeMixin, ErrorMessageMixin, SuccessMessageMixin, FormView):
    model = get_user_model()
    form_class = CodeConfirmationUserForm
    template_name = 'users/code_confirmation.html'
    extra_context = {'title': 'Registration'}
    success_url = reverse_lazy('home')
    success_message = "Registation and authentication have been successfully permormed!"

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        # ... 

    def get_initial(self):
        initial = super().get_initial()
        initial['email'] = self.kwargs.get('email', '')  # Set the initial value for the email field
        return initial
```

**code_confirmation.html**

```
<div class="my-3">
    <label class="w-150 me-2 align-top" for="{{ form.email.id_for_label }}">
        {{ form.email.label }}
    </label>
    {{ form.email }}
</div>
<div class="my-3">
    <label class="w-150 me-2 align-top" for="{{ form.confirmation_code.id_for_label }}">
        {{ form.confirmation_code.label }}
    </label>
    {{ form.confirmation_code }}
</div>
```

**urls.py**

```
from django.urls import path
from users import views

app_name = "users"

urlpatterns = [
    path('register/', views.RegisterUserView.as_view(), name='register'),
    path('code_confirmation/<str:email>', views.CodeConfirmationUserView.as_view(), name='code_confirmation')
]
```

Now the default value for email will be displayed

[image]
[image]